# "This item is localized" when trying to localize component using the core service

Tags: core-service

I'm seeing the below error when trying to update a components content field.

> This item is localized

I have the following code which strips out the content, calls off to a couple of methods that updates the content source xml to that of `replacedContentSource`. I only get an error when trying to localize the component. The reason I am having to do this is because the component content source contains component links linking to a publication not in the content master.

```
public void LocalizeAndAddComponentLinks(CoreServiceClient client, ComponentData component, 
                                         string source)
{
    string contentSource = Tridion.CreateRelatedComponents(client, source);
    string replacedContentSource = Tridion.GenerateTcmIds(contentSource);

    component.Content = replacedContentSource;

    client.Localize(component.Id, new ReadOptions());
    client.Update(component, new ReadOptions());
}
```

I just don't understand why I'm getting this error, the component isn't localized and I've verified this by checking in Tridion.

Comment: This exception can be thrown in case item is local. Also, it's considered a bad practice to use Tridion namespace for something that it not developed by Tridion. Can you check component.IsShared and component.IsLocalized properties?

Comment: Thanks user978511, ok I think I've worked out why I'm seeing the error. IsShared and IsLocalized are both false. IsShared is false because component.Id has the location of where the component was created. If I right click on a component where it was created I can't localize it so this means the problem is that I need to specify "where" exactly I want to localize the component. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: You now specify `component.Id`. You'll indeed need to specify where you want to localize the component. Change the Publication ID of that URI to the publication you want to localize **into** and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I would have accepted your comment as the answer but can't so will add one in myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thought I'd add the answer to this question so everyone knows where the problem was.

Basically I have this `client.Localize(component.Id, new ReadOptions());` meaning I want to localize the component at the level it has been created. This won't work and you can test this by going to the component in Tridion - right click on the component and try to localize, it won't work as the option is grayed out.

So I need to change this line of code to specify the publication Id of where I want to localize this component as already pointed out by Frank too!

I will probably do a `.Replace()` and strip out the publication Id changing it for my target publication.

### UPDATE

Just wanted to share my answer to show you how I've got this working by using a `.Replace()`

```
    public void LocalizeAndAddComponentLinks(CoreServiceClient client, ComponentData component, string source)
    {
        string contentSource = Tridion.ReplaceSystemComponentIdsWithWebsiteMasterId(client, source);
        var localizedComponent = (ComponentData)client.Localize(component.Id.Replace("tcm:xxx-", "tcm:xxx-"), new ReadOptions());
        localizedComponent.Content = contentSource;

        client.Update(localizedComponent, new ReadOptions());
    }
```

As pointed out by user978511 using a `.Replace()` might not be the best approach so I will bed taking a look at the `.GetTcmUri` method to improve my code.

Comment: Instead of replace, consider `.GetTcmUri` method